# How to list PDF files in Android?

Tags: android, file, pdf

I have the following code:

```java
public ArrayList<File> getPDFs(File directory) {
    ArrayList<File> pdfFileList = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] paths = directory.listFiles();
    
    if (!(paths == null)) {
        for (File path : paths) {
            if (path.isFile() && path.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                pdfFileList.add(path);
            }
            else if (path.isDirectory()) {
                getPDFs(path);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return pdfFileList;
}
```

I also have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in my manifest file. When I call this function (e.g., `getPDFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());`) only folders are listed - I can't see any files. I downloaded a sample PDF with Chrome onto the emulator, but it doesn't get listed here. How can I list files (specifically PDF documents) in Android? I'm using Android 11.

Edit: The issue seems to be related to Chrome "owning" the file - my app didn't create the file and therefore cannot read it. I'm not sure how to get around this.

Edit 2: I believe I need to use the Storage Access Framework to access a directory, but again I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/orbitalsonic/PDF-Loader-Android-Kortlin) try the following code you can get all pdf files from a mobile directory.

The code is in Kotlin Language hope you will understand. You should add permissions in manifest

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**LoaderManager.kt**

```
class LoaderManager {

    companion object {

        val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }

        val pdfFileList = ArrayList<FileItem>()


        fun getFilesLoader(
            callback: () -> Unit
        ) {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main + handler) {
                async(Dispatchers.IO + handler) {
                    getFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
                }.await()
                callback.invoke()
            }

        }

        private fun getFiles(dir: File) {
            try {
                val pdfPattern = ".pdf"
                val listFile = dir.listFiles()
                if (listFile != null && listFile.isNotEmpty()) {
                    for (file in listFile) {
                        if (file.isDirectory) {
                            getFiles(file)
                        }
                    }
                    Arrays.sort(
                        listFile
                    ) { file: File, t1: File ->
                        file.lastModified().compareTo(t1.lastModified())
                    }
                    for (file in listFile) {
                        if (file.exists() && file.name.endsWith(pdfPattern)) {
                            pdfFileList.add(FileItem(file))
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        fun isFilesListEmpty() = pdfFileList.isEmpty()

        fun clearFilesData() {
            pdfFileList.clear()
        }

    }
}
```

**LoaderViewModel.kt**

```
class LoaderViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _filesLoad = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    var isFilesLoaded: LiveData<Boolean> = Transformations.map(_filesLoad) { it }

    fun setFilesLoaded(isLoaded: Boolean) {
        _filesLoad.value = isLoaded
    }

    fun getGalleryFiles() {
        if (LoaderManager.isFilesListEmpty()) {
            LoaderManager.getFilesLoader {
                setFilesLoaded(true)
            }
        } else {
            setFilesLoaded(true)
        }
    }

}
```

**FileItem.kt**

```
data class FileItem(
    var pdfFilePath: File
)
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var loaderViewModel: LoaderViewModel
    private lateinit var mAdapter: AdapterFilesLoader
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)

        initViewModel()
        createLoaderRecyclerView()

        if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
                loaderViewModel.getGalleryFiles()
            }else{
                showPermissionDialog()
            }
        } else {
            if (checkReadWritePermission()) {
                loaderViewModel.getGalleryFiles()
            }else{
                requestStoragePermission()
            }
        }

    }

    private fun initViewModel(){
        loaderViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoaderViewModel::class.java)
        loaderViewModel.isFilesLoaded.observe(this) {
            if (it){
                binding.loadingProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                Log.i("PDFTesting","${LoaderManager.pdfFileList.size}")
                mAdapter.submitList(LoaderManager.pdfFileList)
                if (LoaderManager.isFilesListEmpty()){
                    binding.noFilesLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }

            }else{
                binding.loadingProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.noFilesLayout.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createLoaderRecyclerView() {
        mAdapter = AdapterFilesLoader()
        binding.recyclerview.adapter = mAdapter
        binding.recyclerview.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
                showMessage(mAdapter.currentList[position].pdfFilePath.absolutePath)
            }

        })


    }

    private fun checkReadWritePermission(): Boolean {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun requestStoragePermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ),
            STORAGE_PERMISSION
        )
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    private fun requestExternalStorageManager(){
        try {
            val mIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
            mIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
            mIntent.data = Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", packageName))
            openActivityForResult(mIntent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            val mIntent = Intent()
            mIntent.action = Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
            openActivityForResult(mIntent)
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (STORAGE_PERMISSION==requestCode){
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                loaderViewModel.getGalleryFiles()
            } else {
                loaderViewModel.setFilesLoaded(false)
                showMessage("Permission Denied!")
            }
        }

    }


    private var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
                loaderViewModel.getGalleryFiles()
            }else{
                showPermissionDialog()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun openActivityForResult(mIntent:Intent) {
        resultLauncher.launch(mIntent)
    }

    private fun showMessage(message:String){
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        LoaderManager.clearFilesData()
    }

    private fun showPermissionDialog() {

        DialogUtils.permissionDialog(
            this,
            object : OnDialogPermissionClickListener {
                override fun onDiscardClick() {
                    loaderViewModel.setFilesLoaded(false)
                }

                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
                override fun onProceedClick() {
                    requestExternalStorageManager()
                }

            })

    }

}
```

Here I just want to explain. just download the source code you will get the exact source code. In Android 11 or above you just give the setting permission to read the files